# Has the (highly possible) 46th POTUS Joe Biden declared the names of people in his cabinet?

Tags: united-states, cabinet, joe-biden

Has the (highly possible 46th POTUS) Joe Biden told anything about or hinted whom may he include in his cabinet? If it is not declared (most probably) when may he declare it?

Comment: What is the relevance of paragraph 1,  the links,  and the reference to Gary Locke, to the question about who will be in Biden's cabinet.   You look like you are trying to hint at something to do with "Biden will favour China".  I'm highly tempted to delete everything that appears irrelevant here.  Why should I not?

Comment: Gary Locke is not even a "person of Chinese origin"—he was born in Seattle. His father served in the US Army in World War II. Absent some sort of evidence, it's not ok to question someone's loyalty to the country because of their ancestry, nor do I see the relevance to this question.

Comment: As asked, the question seems more suited to a web search than to politics.SE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be highly unusual for a President-Elect to have named his Cabinet before he is deemed elected.  Usually these announcements will be made starting mid-November and continue through to January.

For reference, President Trump made his first Cabinet announcement on November 18, 2016, naming his picks for Attorney General and CIA Director, and he made his final pre-inauguration Cabinet announcement (Agriculture Secretary) on January 18, 2017.